# How to Understand getXrefSize in which Page at PDF with Using Itext in Android

Tags: android, image, pdf, itext

I can get images with getXrefSize from PDF with itext. And i know to images getxrefsize.

```
    PdfReader reader;

File file = new File("example.pdf");
reader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
for (int i = 0; i < reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
    PdfObject pdfobj = reader.getPdfObject(i);
    if (pdfobj == null || !pdfobj.isStream()) {
        continue;
    }
    PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) pdfobj;
    PdfObject pdfsubtype = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
    if (pdfsubtype != null && pdfsubtype.toString().equals(PdfName.IMAGE.toString())) {
        byte[] img = PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw((PRStream) stream);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getParentFile(), String.format("%1$05d", i) + ".jpg"));
        out.write(img);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Also i can get text from pdf. And i know texts in which page.(I am writin PDF to HTML , i am split to every page.) But i do not know how to place images in text .

Answer (score 1):

A PDF document consist of a series of *indirect objects*. These objects can be PDF dictionaries (e.g. the info dictionary), PDF streams (e.g. image streams, content streams containing compressed PDF syntax for pages or form XObjects), PDF strings, and so on.

These objects are listed in the so-called *cross-reference stream* (`xref`) which is a table that contains (among others) the byte offset where a PDF consumer can find the object in the file. For instance: object 1 starts at byte 1280, object 2 starts at byte 518, and so on. (Objects don't need to be ordered by number.)

The method `reader.getXrefSize()` gives you the highest object number in the cross-reference table. You can loop over all the objects in the cross-reference table like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
    PdfObject pdfobj = reader.getPdfObject(i);
}
```

The value of `pdfobj` will be `null` in many cases, because there are usually several gaps in the cross-reference table.

You seem to want to use this mechanism to extract text from each page. However: there is no relation between the object number in the cross-reference table and the page number. Where did you get that code and why did you think it would work?

Please consult [the official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) and read the answer to these questions:

- [Can I change the page count by changing internal metadata?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-i-change-page-count-changing-internal-metadata)
- [How to get the page number of an arbitrary PDF object?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-page-number-arbitrary-pdf-object)

These answers explain how pages are organized inside a PDF and also give you an idea about the concept of PDF object.

If you want to extract text from a page, you'll typically loop over the total number of pages and extract the text page per page like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    String str = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,
        i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
}
```

Make sure you also read the answer to these questions:

- [Why is the text I extract from an English PDF page garbled?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-text-i-extract-english-pdf-page-garbled)
- [How to extract text and anchor information from a PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-extract-text-and-anchor-information-pdf)

There's much more information on the site, but since your question was about `getXrefSize()`, I suggest that you accept this answer and that you post follow-up questions if you want to know more. (I won't answer to comments posted on this answer.)